# How this program with threads works?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I try to learn basics about thread programming in c. And I found some problem which I can't figure it out.
The program write five times five.(Why just five? Why not 1,2,3 or 4)
and what is the difference when I comment line sleep(5) and not?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *dretva (void *x)
{
   sleep(2);
   printf("%d\n", *((int *)x));

return NULL;
}
int main()
{
   pthread_t id[5];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
       pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, dretva, (void*)&i);
   }    
   sleep(5); // why is different when this line is commented?
return 0;
}
```

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>`, needed for the `sleep()` function

Comment: OT: regarding; `return NULL;`  A much better way to exit a thread function is to use the function: `pthread_exit( NULL );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot accurately predict the output in this case because the order in which the threads run is not guaranteed. And because of the `sleep` in each of the threads, it so happens (in this particular case) that the value of `i` has already been incremented to `5` in the `for` loop before the first thread has executed.

If you want to see the output of `i` in an ascending order, just call `pthread_join` in the `for` loop.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, dretva, (void*)&i);
    pthread_join(id[i], NULL);
}
```

See [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f76b0b1235b129b)

Comment: @LovroSindičić: does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

> The program write five times five.(Why just five? Why not 1,2,3 or 4)

When all the threads started executing, the value of `i` was already set to 5 in the main thread. But it is not guaranteed to print 5 five times always. Whatever the value of i at the time of execution of a thread will be, that value will be printed.

> what is the difference when I comment line sleep(5)

The developer of this code is making the main thread wait for 5 seconds. You should use join to block the main thread until the other threads have returned.

Answer (score 1):

You face likely a race condition here. The point is - as Naveen Kumar pointed out - by the time your threads become active, the content at address of i is 5, hence each of your threads prints out what it finds on address of i.
If you alternatively provide the value, you should get your desired result.
With the sleep-statement, you are sending your main thread into background keeping contents at the address of i intact. Without this statement, your main thread terminates thus freeing the memory at address of i. As result your threads may find random numbers to print. If you want to avoid that, try getting familiar with pthread_join.

Comment: That depends on the scheduler, on factors like which priority you assigned, which other threads are active and other factors not in your hand ( such as interrupt load )

Answer (score 0):

You are passing address of i as an argument. After the loop ends, value of i will be 5. All the threads sleeps for 2 seconds and prints the same value.

> (void*)&i

```
pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, dretva, (void*)&i);
```

you can use an array to store the tid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *dretva (void *x)
{
   sleep(2);
   printf("%d\n", *((int *)x));

return NULL;
}
int main()
{
   pthread_t id[5];
   int args[5];
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {   int j;
       args[i] = i; // storing tid
       pthread_create(&id[i], NULL, dretva, &args[i]);
   }    
   sleep(5);
return 0;
}
```